# Installing Firebase 2.4.3 cocoapods

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, podfile

I am trying to install Firebase to my project with cocoapods. I modified pod file by adding line

```
pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.4.3'
```

And when I type `pod install` to terminal it gives me an error:

> [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - `Firebase (>= 2.4.3)` required by `Podfile`

I tried to uncomment and change global "platform" directive to "platform :ios, '9.0'", but it didn't help me, error still there.

Comment: Is not that the latest version of Firebase? Why do you want to specify the version in the podfile?

Comment: It is latest version, previous is 2.4.2. So I wanted to install latest version to avoid potential problems, but it gave me that error. 2.4.2 installing without any errors though.

Comment: Don't specify the version. Trust me, it will install the latest version.

Comment: I thought so, and tried not to specify the version, and it installed 2.4.2. Probably just leave it as it is.

Comment: I have just tried and it installed the lastest version 2.4.3. Try to update Cocoapods.

Comment: I have updated cocoapods, all the same. Could it depend on XCode version?

Comment: Maybe. I am not sore. Sorry.

Comment: Well, thank you for helping me any way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this line:

```
pod 'Firebase', '~> 2.4'
```